# Cannot add button object to Script in Inspector

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, button, inspector

I have a MonoBehaviour script which have slots for buttons to act as a vehicles gas pedal and break pedal but i am unable to drag the button object on those slots.

```
public Mybutton gasPedal;
public Mybutton brakePedal;
public Mybutton leftButton;
public Mybutton rightButton;
```

[image]

It shows that black stop sign when i drag over it. Already checked if there is another script with same name, also tried adding component to the object.

Comment: How is `Mybutton` declared?  Where are you dragging the references from/to?

Comment: Any compiler errors in the Console? Does the object you are dragging have a `Mybutton` component at all?

Comment: There is a seperate script for `Mybutton` Im dragging the "button" which created from UI menu from hierarchy to the car object's script.

Comment: No there are no compiler errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with the help of *derHugo*'s comment. I had an script named `Mybutton` which i had to add as component to the button object.